# Reduce db queries on a recent activity page

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have a very basic 'news feed' page that uses generic relations, with the following model:

```
class RecentActivity(models.Model):
    event_type = models.IntegerField(choices=EVENT_TYPES)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    credits = models.ManyToManyField('videos.VideoCredit', blank=True)
```

I am using signals to listen for when an object is created and checking to make sure it exists (i.e., it was not deleted) in the view before showing it. It is a very basic page, with only a couple dozen lines of code to generate it. However, it is generating tons of db queries! On a page of about 20 recent activity objects, it takes about 120 queries, and I estimate it'll max out around 200 queries.

What would be the best way to get around this? My primary concern is not in reducing the number of queries, but in making the page load as fast as possible. (My first thought was denormalizing.)

Note that the page is not dynamic per-user, but will be the same for all users. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without more information but the usual steps I take are:

1. Use [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) to find out exactly what queries are running
2. Use select_related on the queries that are being caused by following foreign keys
3. Use {% with %} etc. for queries that are being generated by multiple accesses within a template.

Looking at your model, you are probably accessing content_type and then content object.  If you follow credits at all you'll easily hit that number of queries.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would you suggest changing the tables at all -- for example not having a field for `credits`, instead creating a dict for it in the view

Comment: Hard to say, I have lot's of many to many fields and depending upon the application they are either not a performance issue or the bane of my existance.   In general you're better to spend a bit of time optimizing your queries then reworking your database for performance; databases tend to be fast enough if you just work at it.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use django-debug-toolbar to see which queries are being executed and make sure that the number of queries does not grow linearly with the number of elements objects that you display.

Once you've reduced the number of queries to the best of your abilities, try using the Django caching system and cache the view or the template fragment that's causing the slowness.